# How to access html file in Razor pages .Net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am new to .Net and using .Net core to create simple web app. It using Razor pages for views and its static contents for now.

Here is the project structure,

[image]

I can use only .cshtml files for the navigations, like

```
    https://localhost:44391/Home //goes to Home.cshtml

    https://localhost:44391/About //goes to About.cshtml
```

I have a static html file and some required assets placed inside the subfolder called "**Off**" in **Pages** folder.

```
https://localhost:44391/Off
```

I know, I can use Razor page itself. But here I downloaded some third party integration and it provides this and asked me to access in the same hierarchy with html page.

May I know is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to route to that specific html file?

Comment: If the content in Off is static, you want to put Off in the `wwwroot ` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a static html file and some required assets placed inside the subfolder called "Off" in Pages folder.

> `https://localhost:44391/Off`

You can try to call `app.UseFileServer` to [enable the serving of static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usefileserver-for-default-documents).

```
//...

app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Pages/Off")), 
    RequestPath = "/Off"
});


app.UseRouting();

//...
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can try to include your html page content as a partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Pages/Off/index")
```

This is in the case that you just want to show the html page content in your MVC website. If that third party integration requires something special then we will need further explanation of the scenario.